# android - keyboard shows on form despite using adjustResize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to move my layout up when the keyboards shows on my app . I used adjustResize , adjustPan and both of them for the activity but non of them works and it still shows the keyboard on the form and does not move the layout above .

this is my layout  :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          ............... my views 

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

how can I make it works ?

Comment: try adding android:isScrollContainer="false" with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                if (heightDiff > dpToPx(getApplicationContext(), 200)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                    // ... do something here
                }
            }
        });


 public static float dpToPx(Context context, float valueInDp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, metrics);
    }
```

andjust add this in your xml
android:id="@+id/activityRoot"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:id="@+id/activityRoot"**>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          ............... my views 

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for reply , what should I do in onGlobalLayout method ?